# how to understand the information provided by key error python

Tags: python, pandas

The operation is a Subtraction with value in position i+1 less i. The code is:

```
r=61
DHumedad=np.zeros(r)
for t in range(r):
    s2 = df1['Humedad(V/V)'][t]
    s1 = df1['Humedad(V/V)'][t-1]
    if t-1 < 0:
        s1=0
    DHumedad[t] = s2-s1
print DHumedad
```

And the error is: KeyError: -1L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# loops from 0 ... 61
for t in range(r):   
    # tries to access the index "-1"
    s1 = df1['Humedad(V/V)'][t-1]
```

Since indexes always start from 0, you should start the loop from 1, something like this:

```
for t in range(1, r + 1):  
    # code here
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.